# Using Linq to aggregate from array to single var

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an accordion that binds data for each item from an array.
I want that for every time that I bound the data I will loop through all of the array and aggregate all of the items with the same id and create a long string with a name from a cell. In the code the name `oneJob.order_id` does not exist and I don't know why.

```
protected string GetAllProffesions(int orderID)
{
    IEnumerable<string> allProf;
    orderID = 544;
    Job[] curItems = null;
    curItems = JobManager.GetJobs(RangeID, GetParam());
    allProf = from oneJob in curItems
              where oneJob.order_id == orderID
              select oneJob.profession_name;

    return Convert.ToString(allProf);
}
```

Comment: Does your Job class has order_id field ? You can use String.Join to join a string

Comment: Just to be sure: Has your "Job"-class a property or field named "order_id" that is accessible from this method?

Comment: Where does the `Job` come from? Is it a manually created class or a product of an ORM (LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework or NHibernate etc.)?

Comment: Yes Job has order_id and it was created earlier,once i press "." it gives all the proprieties that i have in Job. Job is manually created in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `job` class doesn't have a property called `order_id`. Check your spelling.

Also, you probably don't want to do `Convert.ToString(allProf)`, as I expect this will give you the type name instead of all the professions concatenated. Try this instead:

`string.Join(", ", allProf.ToArray());`